# Cross-platform inheritance of view models

Tags: c#, inheritance, mvvm, cross-platform

So I have run to a problem while trying to follow the MVVM pattern for my WPF project and I spent hours searching for a solution with no luck. The problem is the following: Let's assume that I have a .net Standard library where I have all my view models for my application, for example let's assume that there are the following view models :

> **BaseDropDownMenuViewModel** that inherits from the **BaseControlViewModel**
>
> **AdvancedDropDownMenuViewModel** that inherits from the **BaseDropDownMenuViewModel**
>
> **MultiDropDownViewModel** that inherits from the **AdvancedDropDownViewModel**

The view models contain both the functionality of the controls and variables used for their appear for example a **BackColor** and a **ForeColor** property that are placed in the **BaseControlViewModel**. Now ,even though this is sufficient enough for me, I want to add some properties that apply only for desktop platforms, for example a **MouseOverBackColor** and a **MouseOverForeColor** property and I also need to be able to override the existing ones ex **BackColor**. These properties of course would only make sense on desktop platform and not a mobile platform.

Now I have found two solutions for my problem but both of them are not sufficient enough...

- Create a new .net standard library with an interface that forces the implementation of properties available only for desktop applications and **create a class for every view model of the base library and implement that interface**. In this scenario I will have a huge amount of duplicate code but I will be able to use these classes for my Windows version of my app and the mobile version will not have unused variables for every single one of its controls for example a **MouseOverBackColor** property that it can't take advantage of.
- Which leads us to my second option which is to implement those properties (**MouseOverBackColor**,**MouseOverForeColor**,...) on the **BaseControlViewModel** on the base .net standard library and have all the versions of my app have those variables even though some might not be able to utilize them. That way I want have duplicate code...

I believe that this problem would be easy to solve if C# supported multi inheritance of classes but since it doesn't I am trying to find another "magic" way of solving this issue. Note: I have also searched about tricks to achieve "multi class inheritance" but those that I was interested in were storing the classes as variables in the main class, which none of this is interests me at the moment because the application would require a massive modification to take advantage of this trick...

Comment: Why not make two Interfaces that the ViewModel both implements. They can have overlapping properties, no problem. So your Destop Interface will have one set of props visible and the Mobile one another but you won't have duped code ...

Comment: I don't quite get what you are suggesting, could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: There is no multi inheritance, but you can implement more than one interface. So you can make IDesktopVM and IMobileVM and have MultiDropDownViewModel implement both. Then your respective clients will see the appropriate API but you do not have duplicate code, because it's actually the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with interfaces:

Example - One class, two interfaces

```
public interface IDesktopProperties
{
    Color BackColor {get; set;}
    Color MouseOverBackColor {get; set;}
}

public interface IMobileProperties
{
    Color BackColor {get; set;}
    Orientation ScreenOrientation {get; set;}
}

public class MySuperFancyViewModel : IDesktopProperties, IMobileProperties
{
    public Color BackColor {get; set;}
    public Color MouseOverBackColor {get; set;}
    public Orientation ScreenOrientation {get; set;}
}
```

Now in your Desktop App, you'll have something like

```
// Will only see properties BackColor and MouseOverBackColor
private IDesktopProperties myProps;
public MyDesktopUI( IDesktopProperties properties ) // <= injected: MySuperFancyViewModel 
{
    myProps = properties;
}
```

And accordingly for Mobile

```
// Will only see properties BackColor and ScreenOrientation
private IMobileProperties myProps;
public MyMobileUI( IMobileProperties properties ) // <= injected: MySuperFancyViewModel 
{
    myProps = properties;
}
```